# How would one reimplement 'var that = this' to save a scope reference with Object.prototype.bind()?

Tags: javascript

In [Secrets of Javascript Closures](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/secrets-of-javascript-closures/), Stuart Langridge presents a snippet of code to demonstrate the common usage of a closure in an .onclick callback, and paraphrasing:

```
link.onclick = function (e) {
    var newa = document.createElement("a");
    var that = this; 
    document.body.appendChild(newa);
    newa.onclick = function (e) {
        that.firstChild.nodeValue = "reset";
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    }
}
```

I've recently stumbled upon Kyle Simpsons' Speaker Deck [New Rules For Javascript](https://speakerdeck.com/getify/new-rules-for-javascript) and he mentions that saving the scope of `this` for a closure like `var self = this` or (like in the snippet) `var that = this` is "misguided" and a case for `Object.prototype.bind()`.  < ES5 compatibility aside, I feel more comfortable leaning on language constructs to solve problems rather than use hacks or quick fixes, but in this code snippet, the problem for using `bind`, `apply` or `call` is that both the reference to the enclosing value of `this` and the closure's reference value of `this` are needed.

Is this a case where practicality trumps philosophy?  What can be done?

Comment: In a case like yours where you need a reference to both, I think you cannot avoid saving a reference of the instance. If it makes you feel any cleaner, you could pass the outer instance as an argument to a self invoking anonymous function that wraps around the inner function, but semantically, that would be the same.

Comment: I've seen that used before, and from your description, it makes sense why it's used: using a closure to save the state of the referenced scope.  You're correct though, it's semantically the same, but for some reason just feels _better_, though I could have some sort of chauvinism towards first-class functions over primitives!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't consider your example as a misguided case for `bind` this and that are separate references.  A misguided case for bind would be :

```
var that = this;

var fn = function () {
    that.method();
}

return fn;
```

vs

```
var fn = function() {
    this.method();
} 

return fn.bind(this);
```

Comment: I think this sums up the scope to that rule of thumb

Answer (score 3):

In the general case, if you really do need both `this` and `that` then you cannot just do away with one of the two, can you?

In the case of a click handler, you should be able to do get to the element in question by looking at the event object passed in. I believe it has a `target` property of some kind. So you could use `e` instead of `this` and then bind to get `that` as `this`.

Depending on how your page is structured, you may also be able to traverse the DOM to get from `this` to `that`, especially if you make use of id or class to tag things semantically.

Comment: From my knowledge, I wholly agree.  The example looks like a practical case for saving the reference of 'this'. Preferentially, referencing 'parentNode' from the event parameter of the callback seems like a better reference in this context.  Perhaps the key takeaway is this: Context in code trumps rules of thumb.